# Globally defined instance of SQLite generates error

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to declare an instance of `SQLite Database` globally as a private final variable.

1)why the way i used in the below posted code causes the `logcat` to generate erros and the app crashes.
2)is there any other way so I can define an instance of my DB globally and final?

Java_Code:

```
    public class SQLiteTest00 extends Activity {
    final MyDB myDB = new MyDB(this);
final SQLiteDatabase mySQLiteDB = myDB.getWritableDatabase();
final ContentValues myContVals = new ContentValues();

private final String TABLE_NAME = "MYDATA";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sqlite_test00);

    myContVals.put("name", "loc00");
    myContVals.put("lat", 33);
    myContVals.put("lng", 53);
    myContVals.put("time", "12:30");
    myContVals.put("date", "11/05/2014");
    lodgeIntoDB(myContVals);
}

private void lodgeIntoDB(ContentValues cv) {
    long newID = mySQLiteDB.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

    if (newID == -1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error Commiting Record(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Commited Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Is MyDB your extended version of SQLiteOpenHelper?  Also, why are you creating a final version of a ContentValues?  Could you explain why you need a final copy of the db?  The db will be private to your app by default, that is the way Android does it.  If you extend SQLiteOpenHelper, then you can call the getWritableDatabase() in the onCreate of your main activity and if your db variable is a member variable you will have it.  Maybe I am missing something.  Also, from what I have read, it is best to close the db if you are not using it and then to use the helper class later to get it again if you need to read from or write to it. Thanks.  Ps.  one other thing, anytime I have seen the helper class called to get a copy of the db, it is done inside onCreate or another method not at the top in the variable declartions.  Try moving it into onCreate.